# react navigation undefined is not object

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I've read multiple similar question with the current problem that I am having. I want the user to click on the login button and it will go to the next screen which is contain tab-navigators

The current issue i have is that when the user click the login button, the undefined error pops up. Regarding the username and password authentication, it can be ignored for the time being as right now all I want to understand and how I can click the button and it will navigate to the next screen which is from the "LoginScreen.js" to "FrontPage.js"

**LoginScreen.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
    Platform, 
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    Image,
    AppRegistry,
    TouchableHighlight,
    View,
    Button,
    ScrollView,
    TextInput,


} from 'react-native'
import FrontPage from './FrontPage'
import {TabNavigator, StackNavigator, NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation'
import firebase from 'firebase'

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {

    _onPressLogin(){
        //function tba 

        console.log('login btn pressed')
        this.props.navigation.navigate('FrontPage')

    }




    render() {

        return (
            <ScrollView> 
                <View style = {[styles.container]}> 

                    <Text> Login </Text>
                    <TextInput 
                        label = 'Email Address' 
                        placeholder = 'email@domain.com' 
                        keyboardType = 'email-address'
                        //TBA 
                    />

                    <TextInput 
                        label = 'Password'
                        placeholder = '********'
                        //TBA 
                    />

                   <Button onPress= {this._onPressLogin} 
                    title = 'Login' />


                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }    
}



export default LoginScreen;
```

**FrontPage.js**

```
  import React from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    Button,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    AppRegistry,

} from 'react-native'

import {StackNavigator, TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen';

export default class FrontPage extends React.Component{
    static navigationOptions = {
        tabBarLabel: 'First',
        routeName: 'FrontPage',

    };

    render(){
        const {navigate} = this.props;
        return(
            <View>
                <Text> This is the first page </Text> 
                <Image
                    source = {require('../images/testImage.png')}
                    style = {{width:60, height:60}}>
                </Image>

                <LoginScreen navigation = {navigation} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

import {StackNavigator, TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

import CameraScreen from './screens/CameraScreen'
import ThirdScreen from './screens/ThirdScreen'
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen'
import FrontPage from './screens/FrontPage'

//TAB NAVIGATOR 
var Navigation = TabNavigator({
  Tab1:{screen:FrontPage},
  Tab2:{screen:CameraScreen},
  Tab3:{screen:ThirdScreen}

}, {

  tabBarPosition:'bottom',
  swipeEnabled:false,
  tabBarOptions: {
    showIcon:true,  
    activeTintColor: 'white',
    activeBackgroundColor: 'white',
    inactiveTintColor:'#7f8c8d',
    inactiveBackgroundColor:'#2c3e50',
    style: { backgroundColor: '#2c3e50' },
    labelStyle: {
      frontSize:9.5,

    }
  }
});

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 0):

It has the reference issue, you need to `bind` the `function _onPressLogin` with `this` in `LoginScreen`

```
<Button onPress= {this._onPressLogin.bind(this)} title = 'Login' />
```